# Git merge origin with a branch with slash

Tags: git, merge

I usually merged the branchs using:

```
git merge --no-ff origin/branchName -m "message"
```

The problem is i have one branch with slash "branch/name",
and i want to merge in the same way but i don't know what's happend if i do:

```
git merge --no-ff origin/branch/name
```

or if i could do

```
git merge --no-ff origin branch/name
```

or

```
git merge --no-ff branch/name
```

And if you can say me the differeces between all, it's a plus.

And, yes, i prefer to use the option 'origin'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first version is fine.

Your second version would merge the branches called `origin` and `branch/name` into your brnach and thus make an octopus merge. Or more likely it would fail as you don't have a branch named `origin` most likely.

Your third version would probably not work, or rather merge your local branch called `branch/name` into your current branch or fail if `branch/name` is the branch you are currently at.